# time not showing fully in taskbar Lubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu 20.04LTS the other day. Since then I have fixing 4 or 5 bugs I came across on it thanks to advice found on here. However, can't see a fix for this one:

In the bottom right corner, on the task bar, the world clock looks fine, but, since I installed the Keyboard State Indicator it stopped showing the last digit, the one that shows exact minute time. So it currently shows 20:5 and that's it. Any suggestions how to fix this?

I tried by moving the world clock to various positions, more to the left, but to no avail.

EDIT: This is now solved. All needed be done was to restart the PC and the clock will show full-time. Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you discover bugs, please click the "affects me to" on the [bug tracker](https://launchpad.net/) as the more people impacted allow us to see which ones annoy users allowing us to direct time towards those impacting the most users.

The manual page for the LTS release can be found here https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html

If you read the LXQt documentation (*sorry it's not intended for users; why we created the Lubuntu manual*) you'll note the World Clocks font is set by the style, so your issue is your style & clock setting don't *mix* well and some details cannot be displayed.

You'll either need to switch to [a new LXQt theme](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html) or use different settings for the clock.

Comment: For detailed (somewhat technical) explanation you can see issue raised upstream here - https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-panel/issues/967